# operator does not exist: character varying = uuid

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

This error is pretty common but when I tried to add the answers that I found on this platform it's still didn't work and the problem persist.

I want to associate two tables by the column "mail" in model "Candidate", and  CandidateEmail in model "CandidateExperience".

But when I try to do it and I query the db I get this error

`operator does not exist: character varying = uuid`

Table Candidate Model:

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Candidate = sequelize.define(
    'Candidate',
    {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        unique: false,
      },
      firstName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
      },
      email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    },
  );

  Candidate.associate = (models) => {
    Candidate.belongsTo(models.V2Position);
    // candidate has many candidateExperience linked by column email
    Candidate.belongsTo(models.CandidateExperience, {
      foreignKey: 'CandidateEmail',
      sourceKey: 'email',
    });
  };

  return Candidate;
};
```

Now the model CandidateExperience:

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const CandidateExperience = sequelize.define('CandidateExperience', {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      unique: false,
    },
    CandidateEmail: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    cvPath: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: true,
    },
  });

  CandidateExperience.associate = (models) => {
    CandidateExperience.hasMany(models.Candidate, {
      foreignKey: 'email',
      sourceKey: 'CandidateEmail',
    });
  };

  return CandidateExperience;
};
```

My goal is to query the candidate and get the "candidateExperience" linked to it by the belongsTo.

For example:

```js
 const candidates = await Candidate.findAndCountAll({
      where: {
         V2PositionId: this.positionId,
          },
      include: CandidateExperience,
      required: true,
      duplicate: false,
    });
    return candidates;
  }
```

- I might have some syntax error in the example since I edited it for the post but all the syntax and brackets are correct in my editor.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution and everything was in the association of the columns.

I found the response in the docs of sequelize

```js
// Here we can connect countries and cities base on country code
Country.hasMany(City, {foreignKey: 'countryCode', sourceKey: 'isoCode'});
City.belongsTo(Country, {foreignKey: 'countryCode', targetKey: 'isoCode'});
```

This is how you connect them with this type of relation of has many belong to and a custom column.

Enjoy I hope I will help someone :D